# Cocoa Touch NSRegularExpression patterns

Tags: iphone, regex, html-parsing, nsregularexpression

I have an application that I'm writing, which gets some HTML from a website. I have a string with the HTML, and there are certain tags which I would like to get information from. However, I need to use wildcards, since certain attributes of the tag change after every request. I would like to get information from all tags that I need at once, so I don't need to search through the HTML too much. Can somebody please explain/point me to a tutorial on NSRegularExpression patterns and using it? I have looked online, on Stackoverflow, and on the Apple Documentation, and I didn't find anything helpful. Also, if somebody knows another way for me to do the same thing, please post as well.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and leave this here http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: I was able to do it just fine. Thanks for the warning, but I am much happier parsing HTML with Regex than with NSXMLParser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the NSRegularExpression documentation online, and after I understood the basics of regex patterns in general it was easier to understand it. If you look online you can find many regex pattern explanations, and the NSRegularExpression documentation is available here for iOS: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and for OS X Lion:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an NSXMLParser instead? I'm not sure if it would suit your specific application, but it would only require going through the HTML string once. You can simply have one "if" statement per tag, so wildcards aren't really needed either.

If you haven't used NSXMLParser before, the [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html) is very helpful.

Comment: I have attempted using NSXMLParser already for this task, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I was receiving errors, and after trying to think ahead I realized that it just made more sense to use other methods.